# Add python_opencv in buildroot image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, buildroot

How can I generate an image using buildroot with opencv2 in it?

In "Target Packages->Libraries->Graphics->opencv2.4" says that python_opencv depends on numpy, which isn't available.

An self made app(which is in the built image as well) uses python3.6 and opencv2.

Buildroot Version: 2017.08-rc3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back when `opencv` was introduced in Buildroot, there was indeed no `numpy` package, so support for doing OpenCV in Python could not be added, hence this comment. But since then, a `python-numpy` package was added, and it is even used in the `opencv3` package to provide Python support.

So, the `opencv` package simply needs to be updated to leverage the python-numpy package to provide Python support.

As a side note: why are you using 2017.08-rc3 ? It is a release candidate, not even a final release. And why this version ? Why not using the LTS version 2018.02.x, which we maintain during one year with security updates and bug fixes ?

Comment: About the version of buildroot: that's a good question! Was not my decision. Maybe was the last version at the time we started development.

Comment: Well, just switched for python 3 and updated buildroot to 2018.02.x. Everything is working fine now. Thanks!